# How to query for starts with more than

Tags: regex, mongodb

I have values like this one in my db

`ale`

I would like to get the result `ale` when I query for `alexander`

I tried to do it like this, `new MongoRegex("/^alexander/i")` but no luck, how can i overcome this issue and get the result `ale` when I query for `alexander`

I am trying to do url matching system, when a user sets matching for `asd.com/cat` I have to match `asd.com/cat/car` and `asd.com/cat/home`, etc. I am trying to accomplish this, thank you

Comment: Why would you expect `ale` to match when you search for `alexander`? Why wouldn't you search for `ale` if you want everything that starts with `ale`?

Comment: @BrianStephens I am trying to do url matching system, It was just an example, when a user sets matching for `asd.com/cat` I have to match `asd.com/cat/car` and `asd.com/cat/home`, etc. I am trying to accomplish this, I can only query with the values `asd.com/cat/home`

Comment: `/^asd.com\/cat/` would match both example urls, so I still don't see the problem.

Comment: @BrianStephens yes, would match it, but I would like to query with `asd.com/cat/car` so I can warn the user, when the urls matched with wildcard, I am trying to query `asd.com/cat/home` to find `asd.com/cat`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to match any url wit same form up to last slash. Im afraid you will have to do it in two steps. Fisrt isolate the first part of url with

```
.*\/
```

this will match asd.com/cat/ . And then you can search for this string with anything after it.

```
^asd.com/cat/.*
```